# Encrypting a string

Tags: java, encryption

May i know what should i do if i want to encrypt 40 characters but i only able to encrypt the first character with the code i did.

```
    System.out.println("Enter character: ");
    sentence = scan.nextLine();
    String random;
    System.out.println("Enter random character: ");
    random = scan.nextLine();


    conv = random.charAt(sentence.indexOf(sentence));
    back = sentence.charAt(random.indexOf(conv));

    System.out.println("U want to encrypt or decrypt?");
    answer = scan.nextLine();



   if(answer.equals("encrypt"))
   {
    System.out.println("The original character is:" +sentence);
    System.out.println("The encrypted character is:" +conv);
   }
   else
    {
    System.out.println("The decrypted character is:" +back);

    }
    // TODO code application logic here
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious that only one character will get encrypted when you are excuting the statements only once. You need to use a loop to go through all the characters in the entered string. Let me give you an example:

```
String conv = "";
for (int i = 0; i < senentence.length(); i++) {
    conv.append(...);
}
```

What you append, depends on the algorithm you use and how long the entered strings are. Using `random.charAt(i)` would just use the random string, and eventually throw an exception.